# Strange user behaviour with regards to tag synonyms

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonym-process, behavior

I noticed recently that a user has edited a bunch of questions to create a new tag, only to then file a tag synonym request for that tag. Aside from being a waste of time, is there anything wrong with this behaviour? I can't see any logical reason for it, and they have done it with multiple tags.

Here are all the questions for the [array-combine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/array-combine) tag, all of which had this tag added last week. The synonym request was filed the next day.

[Array_combine more than 2 arrays from POST form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17777996/array-combine-more-than-2-arrays-from-post-form)

[PHP - merge two arrays similar to array_combine, but with duplicate keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9078770/php-merge-two-arrays-similar-to-array-combine-but-with-duplicate-keys)

["Array_combine" with associative arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8660249/array-combine-with-associative-arrays)

[php array_combine only if keys match](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8137242/php-array-combine-only-if-keys-match)

Comment: @yellowantphil that was my first thought (in fact I noticed this because I thought I'd go for the badge myself) but it's only awarded once and the user in question just got it recently.