# Burnination request: [jquery-contents]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, burninate-request

I stumbled over the [jquery-contents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery-contents) tag in the review queue today. I don't see any reason why a specific function of the query framework would need to have its own tag. There are just 10 questions tagged with it, all of them also tagged with [jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery).

Since I'm not an expert in javascript/jquery, I would like to have an expert to have a look at this.

Comment: Looking at this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9231663/difference-between-using-html-and-contents) it looks like a method but it's definitely not tag worthy in my opinion. This looks to be the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/contents/) for `contents`.

Comment: I'm hesitant to post as an answer because I don't feel like I've got the...authority? to decide (I'm not a regular meta user and generally only look in on burninate requests out of curiosity). But as someone who knows jQuery: oh god, burninate the hell out of that. There's no way a single function of the jQuery API should have *its own tag.*

Comment: I also agree it's not tag worthy and it should be removed and/or migrated to `jquery`.

Comment: 10 questions... just retag and be done with it

Comment: I was tempted to do this request too, to add why it should be burninated, doesn't add any meaningful information to the post is more a function used as solution for some problems than a topic related with the problem itself, and if already tagged with Jquery people following that are able to answer it. Also 2+years and just 1 follower / 10 questions most of all tagged by the same user this year ... Burninate this

Comment: By the way: http://stackoverflow.com/users/5104748/?tab=activity&sort=suggestions

Comment: For ten questions in the tag, if you've got the knowledge and reputation to make the changes, simply go ahead and do it.  I can see that BDL isn't sure about having the knowledge — it is reasonable to ask.  If the number of questions is up into the hundreds, then you need tooling support, or the patience of Job, to do the job.

Comment: See also my question about the user that created this tag: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/347824/strange-user-behaviour-with-regards-to-tag-synonyms This guy really likes tagging stuff.

Comment: The [tag:jquery-content] is a tag like [tag:jquery-animate], [tag:jquery-hover], [tag:preg-replace], [tag:str-repalce] and many other tags that is relevant to a function and many post has they tags. So [tag:preg-replace] should removed because it posts has [tag:php] tag?

Comment: @Mohammad Honestly...burninate all of them. For example, [tag:preg-replace] could be handled just as well with [tag:php] [tag:regex] no?

Comment: @Draco18s or at the very most a php-preg tag

Comment: @Draco18s Yes, Also use only [tag:javascript] instead of [tag:jquery] or [tag:angular]

Comment: jQuery and Angular are entire, massive, toolsets all their own. They need their tags. It is entirely possible to be an expert in jQuery and *not* in Angular.  Just because both are written--and used--in Javascript does not mean that a javascript expert who's never used either is going to be able to answer questions about them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All questions have been removed from the tag. Thanks to whoever did it.